# Vertically Aligning placehoder text to the top

Tags: css

The placeholder text appears vertically aligned in the center which is fine with the Name and email fields but not with the Text field. I want it to be aligned to the top (the height of the text field is 100px).

Here is the CSS I've used:

```
form {
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

input {
    font-weight: 300;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
}

input[type="text"] {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    width: 250px;
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
}

input[type="submit"] {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    width: 272px;
    height: 40px;
    border: none;
    background: steelblue;
    color: white;
}

input[class="text-field"] {
    height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: could you post your HTML too pls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want this text field to contain multi-line text (since you're setting its height to 100px), in which case you might want to use a [`<textarea>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea) instead. The switch should solve your vertical alignment problem.

Comment: It works. I thought <input> was the default/standard way to go. Thanks